# Is there a way of running two spiders with a Crawl.runner / process and save the results in two separate files?

Tags: python, process, scrapy, web-crawler, twisted

I have two scrapy spiders in two different scripts

```
Spiders
 Spider1.py
 Spider2.py
```

An example of the code in the spiders is as follows:

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from twisted.internet import reactor

   class Spider(scrapy.spider):
     # some code

   runner = CrawlerRunner(
       settings={'FEEDS': 
       {'../input/next.csv': {'format': 
        'csv'}}})
   runner.crawl(Spider)
   d = runner.join()
   d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
   reactor.run()
```

I am running both spiders from a separate script with the following code:

```
import runpy as r



def run_webscraper():
       r.run_path(path_name='Spider1.py') 
       r.run_path(path_name='Spider2.py')
       return
   if __name__ == '__main__':
       run_webscrapper()
```

When I try to run the spiders, Spider1 runs and saves the results in the corresponding csv file but when executes spider2 I get the following error:

twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable

Any ideas on how to fix the code so that the two spiders run and save their results in separate files (spider1.csv, spider2.csv)?

Is this actually possible?

Comment: Do both of your spider1 and spider2 have the same class name? and do you really need to use runpy to call your python files? I think it will be better if only use one spider class and rework it to be able to manage different requests under the same reactor. That error exists because the current reactor has been stopped when your spider2.py tries to call it again.

Comment: I will try that. I definitely need to reorganise the code. Thanks for your answer Taipei

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can do this by creating a cutom setting within each spider like this:

spider1:

```
class Spider1(scrapy.Spider):
  name='spider1'
  custom_settings = {
    'FEEDS': {
      'spider1.csv': {
        'format': 'csv'
      }
    }
  }
```

spider2:

```
class Spider2(scrapy.Spider):
name='spider2'
custom_settings = {
  'FEEDS': {
    'spider2.csv': {
      'format': 'csv'
    }
  }
}
```